# Problems on booting Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 20.04, keyboard

I am having a weird issue when booting on dual boot alongside Windows 10, the problem can be described as follows:

1. Turn on the PC.
2. The motherboard makes a weird sound when starting (it didn't happen before).
3. Ubuntu starts automatically without entering the GRUB menu but the screen is frozen, I can run some commands with the keyboard but the mouse doesn't work properly.
4. I restart the PC using the <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> command.
5. Everything starts perfectly even the GRUB menu works well and there is not a weird sound and I can use the computer smoothly until the next shut down.

I know this is not a disastrous problem but it is annoying to restart the PC all the time, thanks for your time.

Comment: What's the "weird sound"? Beeps (how many?), rotary grinding, power supply transformer vibration, cat stuck in the mechanism?

Comment: It is a 1 long beep and 3 short ones, I checked the Motherboard guide and it said is a problem with the VGA, I tried changing the NVIDIA driver and it didn't solve it.